# Initialising controlled number fields empty in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem with having a controlled number input which I want to be empty on first load.

Component code is something like the following (this is simplified to be an extremely minimal example, the actual form has more fields and some display structure);

```
interface IFormProps {
    initialItem: IItem;
}

interface IFormState {
    item: IItem;
}

export class Form extends React.Component<IFormProps, {}> {
    state: IFormState;

    constructor(props: IFormProps) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

        this.state = {
             item: cloneDeep(props.initialItem)
        };
    }

    render() {
        const item = this.state.item;

        return (
            <input type="number" value={item.rate} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        );
    }

    handleChange() {
        // field change handling code including updating the state
    }
}
```

On item, the rate field is of type number.

I want the given field to be empty when the form is first loaded. If item.rate starts off null, however, I get the following console error initially;

> Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using the empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.

On typing a number in the field, I then get the console error;

> Warning: Form is changing an uncontrolled input of type number to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Using undefined initially gets rid of the first warning, but still brings up the second on entering a value.

With similar fields of type text (string in the typescript), initiating as the empty string gives the correct result, but I can't do that here because the item.rate is of type number.

Is there a way round this, so that the field will be empty until the user enters something without any of these console errors appearing?

Comment: Can you try value={item.rate || ''}

Comment: Brilliant, that does work! (Now I feel silly - I hadn't thought to put it there where it's not types rather than on the item)

Comment: Although for the benefit of anyone looking at this later, if you might be passing in 0 as the value of item.rate, and want 0 to appear in the field in that case (so only being clear if item.rate is null or undefined), you'll need an extra check because 0 is falsy (so 0 || '' is '').

Comment: True, how about value={item.rate !== null ? item.rate : ''}

Comment: Depends on whether you know whether item.rate might be undefined rather than null (in which case you might want to explicitly take the zero case out and let all other falsy values go to '' - or alternatively have value={item.rate == null ? '' : item.rate}). But that's somewhat academic.